# How Efficiently load XIB to Use In UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uipickerview

I have a custom `UIPickerView` which present a list of countries.
Using this method I can supply custom `UIView` object for each row:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

So currently i'm loading the view from `XIB` file and setting his content accordingly:

```
UIView *pickerRowView = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CountryRow"];

pickerRowView.text = text;
pickerRowView.image = image;
```

the views loaded correctly and all content is show.
but the problem is that it get laggy some times, i fell it a bit slow.
how can i build this mechanism to be more efficient or eve build my own dequeueing mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView *pickerRowView = [self viewTLoad]; 

-(UIView *)viewTLoad{
    NSArray *myNibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyVoucherSpyTabBarView" owner:self options:nil];
    MyVoucherSpyTabBarView * TabView  = [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    return TabView;
}
```

Comment: but how this implementation is different? it will go and load the xib each time

Comment: are you loading it single time or multiple time? your code directly accesing view from xib, so i thought it may problem, then i loaded into array and get it.Where are you loading your view?

Comment: -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view 
{
UIView *pickerRowView = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CountryRow"];
  pickerRowView.text = text; 
  pickerRowView.image = image;
  return pickerRowView;
}

this is how i load views today, what you suggest is basically the same